# OnActionExecuting gets called when loading images on Firefox & IE but not on Chrome

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, action-filter

I was just testing a my code in an `OnActionExecuting` action and i noticed that chrome is acting differently than Firefox & IE.

Firefox & IE also fires the `OnActionExecuting` action on images (maybe more?) and chrome does not.

I requested the property: `filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.CurrentExecutionFilePathExtension`
which gives me the extension of the requested url. In my case it was: `".png"

Why isn't chrome firing this action?

*Note: (I have not tested any further, i stopped when i noticed it fires images. The only browsers i tested are IE & Firefox)*

Has this something to do with ASP.NET MVC or with the browser?

Comment: pleas add code that we can test it...

Comment: You can create an OnActionExecuting method that inherits from ActionFilterAttribute. I'm doing nothing else special.

Comment: Is this possibly because chrome is caching the images so not actually making the call to the server?